# independent variables probability comparision

Tags: probability, independence

If Event A and B are independent: P(A∩B) = P(A)P(B)

If A and B are not independent:

Question1,   Does P(A)P(B) means anything? is it meaningful?

Question2,   How to analyze the comparison between P(A∩B) and P(A)P(B), when is bigger when is smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when $A$ and $B$ are not independent,

$P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|\bar A)P(\bar A)=P(A,B)+P(\bar A,B)$.

Thus, mathematically $P(A)P(B)=P(A)[P(A,B)+P(\bar A,B)]$.

If $P(B)\geq P(B|A)$, since $P(B|A)=\frac{P(A,B)}{P(A)}$, then $P(A)P(B) \geq P(A,B)$. Or symmetrically, if $P(A)\geq P(A|B)$, we also have $P(A)P(B) \geq P(A,B)$.

Otherwise, $P(A)P(B) < P(A,B)$.

Comment: In view of the symmetric roles of $A$ and $B$, one might expect that it would be equally possible th cone up with the condition $P(A) \geq P(A\mid B)$ as being what ensures that $P(A)P(B) \geq P(A,B)$. So, are the two conditions $P(B) \geq P(B\mid A)$ and $P(A) \geq P(A\mid B)$ the same condition (if one holds, so does the other) or does either work (either one is sufficient) or are both necessary?

Comment: @ Dilip Sarwate: Yes, you are right. I just updated above answer correspondingly. Thanks.